# How to ring multi numbers at the same time, but qualify pick up with a digit response?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I want to set Twilio up to ring multiple numbers at the same time with a 30s time out. I see this can be done with a dial verb but I need to add some logic that <say>s a message to the recipient asking them to press any digit to be connected. First recipient that presses a digit gets connected, and all other calls stop. If timeout and no digit pressed, plays another voicemail message, allowing caller to leave a VM.

I tried the dial verb, but this didn't work needs more logic.

Comment: This would be illegal in a lot of jurisdictions, and fall under robo-call/nuisance-call legislation which forbids this type of practice.